# JTable click and show new window

Tags: java, jtable, mouselistener

I have JTable which shows data from arraylist through AbstractTableModel.

What I want to do is when I click (left-click) on row in JTable, I want to show new window where can I see and edit data from row stored in arraylist.

I have MouseListener already written, but it does nothing.

There are main,table and tablemodel classes.

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private Controller controller;
    private Prihlasovanie prihlasovanie;
    private TabulkaSkladnik tabulkaskladnik;
    private Okno okno;       

    public MainWindow() {

            super("PROJEKT OOP");
            setVisible(true);
            setSize(750, 508);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800,500));

            controller = new Controller();
            tabulkaskladnik = new TabulkaSkladnik();
            prihlasovanie = new Prihlasovanie();

            tabulkaskladnik.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {          
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            Okno okno =  new Okno();
                            okno.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    });


            JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
            getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);


            tabbedPane.addTab("Prihlasovanie", null , prihlasovanie , null);
            tabbedPane.addTab("Skladnik", null , tabulkaskladnik , null);

            tabulkaskladnik.setData(controller.getObjednavky());

            }
}

public class TabulkaSkladnik extends JTable {

    private JTable tabulka;
    private SkladnikTableModel tabulkaModel;

    public TabulkaSkladnik() {

        tabulkaModel = new SkladnikTableModel();
        tabulka = new JTable(tabulkaModel);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(new JScrollPane(tabulka),BorderLayout.CENTER);      
    }

    public void setData(List<Objednavka> databaza) {
        tabulkaModel.setData(databaza);
    }

    public void refresh() {
        tabulkaModel.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
    }


public class SkladnikTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Objednavka> databaza;  
    private String[] colNames = {"ID", "Nazov", "Popis", "Meno", "Priezvisko"};

public SkladnikTableModel() {       
    }   
    public void setData(List<Objednavka> databaza) {
        this.databaza = databaza;
    }   
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return colNames[column];
    }   
    public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
           return getValueAt(0,col).getClass();
         }
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 5;
    }
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return databaza.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int riadok, int stlpec) {
        Objednavka objednavka = databaza.get(riadok);

        switch(stlpec) {
        case 0: return objednavka.getId();
        case 1: return objednavka.getNazov();
        case 2: return objednavka.getOpis();
        case 3: return objednavka.getMeno();
        case 4: return objednavka.getPriezvisko();
        }   
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: You can make your table's rows selectable and in the `mouseClicked(....)` method get the selected row and use it to create the `Okno` window.

Comment: What do you mean when you say your mouse listener does nothing? Does it even cause a new Okno to display? Even if it does, you have to detect the selected row and get that information into your Okno object if you want to display/edit it.

Comment: Mouselistener doesn`t show new Okno window, I dont know why.

Comment: What kind of debugging have you done? Did you add a `System.out.println(...)` to your MouseListener to see if the code is executed? Why did you post the TableModel code? A TableModel has nothing to do with clicking on a JTable. Also, all GUI components should be added to the frame BEFORE you make the frame visible?

Comment: Yes of course, I added System.out.println(..) and the code isn´t executed. I change adding GUI component, but it didn´t solve the problem.

Comment: Does the table row you click on highlight, showing that it got selected? Make sure your selection mode on your table is set.